# valgrind installation using brew on macOS High Sierra 10.13.2

Tags: homebrew, valgrind, macos-sierra

I get the following error when trying to install valgrind on the version of macOS using brew:

> valgrind: This formula either does not compile or function as expected
>   on macOS versions newer than Sierra due to an upstream
>   incompatibility. Error: An unsatisfied requirement failed this build.

I have tried to follow suggestions from all related posts on the issue, and even tried building valgrind using the *./configure* option after downloading the source tarball. But that too fails with a gcc incompatibility error, which I am unable to overcome, despite following workaround suggestions on the Web.

Any help would be appreciated.

TIA

Vinod

Comment: AFAIK, Valgrind does not run on macOS High Sierra yet.  I'd be delighted to be proved wrong, but …

Answer (score 5):

`brew install --HEAD valgrind` seems to work now.

See [this issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/18998) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to build it directly and install instead of using home-brew. I have created a port of valgrind 3.13.0 to work on macOS High Sierra (10.13.x). You can get it here: https://github.com/padiakalpesh/valgrind_3.13_high_sierra

Once you have obtained the source, run the following commands from inside the source directory:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```